# Making POST to DRF using Axios

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to make a simple `POST` request using `axios` library inside of `vuejs` but for some reason, `DRF` is not receiving the parameters. When the same request is made via `Postman` it receives the parameters.

**VueJS**

```
postLogin(credentials){
    return axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "company/login/",
      data: credentials,
    }).catch(err => {
      return TreatErrors.treatDefaultError(err);
    })
  }
```

**DRF**

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    # Debug set here shows POST comes empty from vuejs
    def login(self, request, pk=None):
        if not request.POST.get('email'):
            raise ValidationError({
                'message': 'You must provide an email'
            })
```

Using the `Chrome DevTools` I can clearly see the parameters are being sent to `DRF`

[image: chrome dev tools]

**What I have tried**
I have tried coping every `Headers` from `Postman` and paste it in `axios` but without any luck

```
postLogin(credentials){
    return axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "company/login/",
      data: credentials,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      return TreatErrors.treatDefaultError(err);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I was accessing the data in the wrong way:

From this:

```
if not request.POST.get('email'):
 raise ValidationError({
   'message': 'You must provide an email'
 })
```

To This

```
data = request.data

if not data.get('email'):
  raise ValidationError({
    'message': 'You must provide an email'
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! God bless! :)